# addSubview to tableViewCell that follows UISlider

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uislider

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jy1p4a9ohp2c2bx/Screenshot%202017-12-10%2019.29.01.png?dl=0
[image]

I'm trying to create a label inside a tableviewcell that follows the uislider. It all works if I don't put the label inside the tableviewcell. But when trying to add the label as a subview to the cell it won't follow the slider. Any idea what I'm missing here?

```
@objc func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
    let value = sender.value
    sender.setValue(Float(lroundf(value)), animated: true)
    ratingValue = Int(sender.value)
    ratingLabel.text = String(ratingValue)

    let cell = self.addRecordTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 8, section: 0)) as! RatingCell
    cell.addSubview(ratingLabel)
    ratingLabel.center = setUISliderThumbValueWithLabel(slider: sender)
}

@objc func setUISliderThumbValueWithLabel(slider: UISlider) -> CGPoint {
    let slidertTrack : CGRect = slider.trackRect(forBounds: slider.bounds)
    let sliderFrame : CGRect = slider.thumbRect(forBounds: slider.bounds, trackRect: slidertTrack, value: slider.value)
    return CGPoint(x: sliderFrame.origin.x + slider.frame.origin.x + 12, y: slider.frame.origin.y - 30)
}
```

Comment: why don´t simply put your label in your cell prototype and change his value in the slider action instead

Comment: I can't quite picture your view. How is a UITableViewCell following a UISlider? Could you post a visual representation of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @ReinierMelian. You mean like changing the AutoLayoutConstraints? Didn't even think about that option. Thanks for putting me in another direction!

Comment: Yes, instead of add the `UILabel` you must have the `UILabel` in your cell and when the Slider action is called update your label

Comment: always use cell.contentView.addSubview() rather than cell.addSubview()